# Uncaught TypeError : undefined is not a function when call of http.request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http, typeerror

I just start using Javascript and Nodejs, and I have the following problem :
**Uncaught TypeError : undefined is not a function**, when I call http.request(...). I am trying to use http.request from client-side in a html page. My code is the following one :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

[...]

<script>
var http=require(['./bower_components.httpjs/http.js'], function(http) {
    alert('HTTP Loaded') ;
});

if (http === undefined') {
    alert('HTTP undefined') ;
}
var options = { 
    [...]
} ;

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    [...]
});
```

I also tried to put this code into the callback function of require('http') and I got a similar error : Uncaught TypeError : **cannot read property 'request' of undefined**. But I find this error strange, because 'request' is a method and not a property.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

[...]

<script>
var http=require(['./bower_components.httpjs/http.js'], function(http) {
    alert('HTTP Loaded') ;
    if (http === undefined') {
        alert('HTTP undefined') ;
    }
    var options = { 
        [...]
    } ;

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        [...]
    });

});
```

Another thing I noticed : in the second version of my code, the variable http seems to be undefined, whereas in the first version the alert('HTTP undefined') doesn't show up.

Does someone have an idea how I could resolve this problem? I really need some help ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not suprised that something is not a _fonction_ :)

Comment: Indeed ! I have just checked it, it's a fonction in the second version. But I don't understand why. In my mind it should be an object. How can I call 'request' then?

Comment: You're missing closing quotes on your `src` attributes in two of your script tags. That could be causing the libraries not to load.

Comment: (Things are never *fonctions*.  Sometimes things are *functions* though.)

Comment: Sure, it's a reflex that comes from the French :p

Comment: And no, the libraries are correctly loaded - I just forget the quotes when I wrote the code here.

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I can think of is that having two variables named `http` might be causing a problem. Usually you try to avoid naming a local variable and a global variable with the same name.

Comment: I tried to rename but I didn't solve the problem. Does some one know why my `var http`  is a function when I define it like this : `var http = require(['http'], function(http) { } ) ;

Comment: are you sure about that path ? `./bower_components.httpjs/http.js`

Comment: Yes I am ! At the beginning I had dependency problems with http.js. It needed underscore.js so I included it, and since that moment it seems to load http.js fine